# Examples for using fipy.steppers.pidStepper

Tags: python-3.x, pde, stepper, fipy

I'm using FiPy to simulate a moderately large system of coupled PDEs (11 equations) that calculate the time-dependent evolution of a biochemical advection-diffusion-reaction network. Currently I'm using a fixed time step, and it works fine. However, the nature of the model is such that during the initial time steps the variables change a lot, this requires a small value of `dt`. After a while the model 'burns in' and the variable changes are much more gradual with time. To save on computational resources, the `dt` could then be increased. Looking at the documentation, the `fipy.steppers.pidStepper` seems ideally suited to this. The documentation on the stepper is, however, very scant and I could not find any code examples that have implemented this (either in the FiPy examples themselves, or from a general internet search).

The skeleton of the evaluation loop currently looks as follows (I'd be happy to provide more details if needed); `v` is an array of 11 cell variables, and `p[j]` is the PDE for `v[j]`:

```python
# steps, err and u defined elsewhere 
for step in range(steps):
    r = [1e3] * len(v)
    while max(r) > err:
        for j in range(len(v)):
            r[j] = min(r[j], p[j].sweep(v[j], dt=u))

    for j in range(len(v)):
        v[j].updateOld()
```

Any pointers on how to adapt this for `pidStepper` would be appreciated. One requirement would be that I need to be able to specify the saving of model outputs at a set of given time points. These are however much further apart than the intial value of `dt` used. But if the step size is adaptive, it might not 'land' exactly on one of these time points, so how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

[`PIDStepper`](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/fipy/generated/fipy.steppers.html#fipy.steppers.pidStepper.PIDStepper) is pretty archaic (last *substantive* change was about [fourteen years ago](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/commits/master/fipy/steppers/pidStepper.py)) and, as you've found, is [neither documented](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/issues/620) nor used anywhere publicly. Since we don't test it, either, we should probably [cornfield](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Recap/TheTwilightZoneS3E73ItsAGoodLife) it.

That said, after rummaging around on my hard drive, I've found a few cases where I experimented with it and, amazingly, it still works.

Using a trivial diffusion problem as an example:

```py
import fipy as fp
from fipy.tools import numerix

nx = 50
dx = 1.
L = nx * dx
mesh = fp.Grid1D(nx=nx, dx=dx)
x = mesh.cellCenters[0]

phi = fp.CellVariable(mesh=mesh, name=r"$\phi$", hasOld=True)

phi.value = 0.
phi.setValue(1., where=(x > L/2. - L/10.) & (x < L/2. + L/10.))

viewer = fp.Viewer(vars=phi, datamin=-0.1, datamax=1.1)

D = 1.
eq = fp.TransientTerm() == fp.DiffusionTerm(D * (1 - phi))

total_elapsed = 0.

dt = 100. * dx**2 / (2 * D)
totaltime = 1000.
checkpoints = (fp.numerix.arange(int(totaltime / dt)) + 1) * dt
```

To solve this with `PIDStepper`, you need to define a `sweepFn()` to actually solve your equation(s). The `vardata` argument is a tuple of tuples, each of which holds a `CellVariable` to solve for, the equation to apply, and the old-style boundary conditions to use (all of this radically predates coupled equations or constraints). The `dt` argument is the adapted time step to attempt. `*args` and `**kwargs` are any additional agruments you wish to pass at each step. This function must return an error normalized to one; here we return the L1 norm of `var - var.old` normalized to the L1 norm of `var.old`.

```py
def L1error(var):
    denom = numerix.L1norm(var.old)
    return numerix.L1norm(var - var.old) / (denom + (denom == 0))

def sweepFn(vardata, dt, *args, **kwargs):
    error = 0.
    for var, eqn, bcs in vardata:
        res = eqn.sweep(var=var, 
                        dt=dt,
                        boundaryConditions=bcs)
        error = max(error, L1error(var))

    return error
```

You can optionally define a `successFn()` to perform after a successful adaptive solution step. The `vardata` argument is as above. The `dt` argument is the time step that was requested. The `dtPrev` argument is the time step that was actually taken. The `elapsed` argument is how much time is elapsed for *this time step*. `*args` and `**kwargs` are any additional agruments you wish to pass at each step *and must be the same as for `sweepFn()`*. Here, we'll want access to the `viewer`, the list of time steps that were taken `dts`, the list of elapsed times each was taken at `elapseds`, and the global clock `total_elapsed`.

```py
def successFn(vardata, dt, dtPrev, elapsed, viewer, dts, elapseds, total_elapsed, *args, **kwargs):
    dts.append(dtPrev)
    elapseds.append(total_elapsed + elapsed)
    viewer.plot()
```

You could also optionally define a `failFn()` to perform whenever `sweepFn()` returns an error greater than one. This would take the same arguments as `successFn()`.

Finally, instantiate a `stepper` with appropriate `vardata` and call `step()` for each desired time step. Pass the desired time step `dt`, the time step to try first `dtTry`, the smallest time step to allow `dtMin`, the last time step attempted `dtPrev`, the `sweepFn()` we just defined, the `successFn()` we just defined, and the optional arguments that our `successFn()` makes use of.

```py
from fipy.steppers import PIDStepper
stepper = PIDStepper(vardata=((phi, eq, ()),))

pid_dts = []
pid_elapseds = []

dtMin = dt / 1000
dtTry = dtMin
dtPrev = dtTry
for until in checkpoints:
    dtPrev, dtTry = stepper.step(dt=dt, dtTry=dtTry, 
                                 dtMin=dtMin, dtPrev=dtPrev,
                                 sweepFn=sweepFn,
                                 successFn=successFn,
                                 viewer=viewer,
                                 dts=pid_dts,
                                 elapseds=pid_elapseds,
                                 total_elapsed=total_elapsed)
    total_elapsed += dt
```

You could also do a similar thing by defining a [`PseudoRKQSStepper`](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/fipy/generated/fipy.steppers.html#fipy.steppers.pseudoRKQSStepper.PseudoRKQSStepper):

```py
stepper = PseudoRKQSStepper(vardata=((phi, eq, ()),))
```

and use the same `sweepFn()` and `successFn()`.

### My current practice

While this works, I found the whole process of defining and passing around helper functions to be kind of opaque and more trouble than it's worth. Until now, I couldn't be bothered to document it or show anybody else how I'd used it.

These days, I do something more like this:

```py
explicit_dts = []
explicit_elapseds = []

dt = dt / 1000
for until in checkpoints:
    while total_elapsed < until:
        phi.updateOld()
        dt_until = (until - total_elapsed)
        dt_save = dt
        if dt_until < dt:
            dt = dt_until
        res = eq.sweep(var=phi, dt=dt)
        
        if L1error(phi) < 1.:
            total_elapsed += dt

            explicit_dts.append(dt)
            explicit_elapseds.append(total_elapsed)

            dt = dt_save
            
            dt *= 1.2
            
            viewer.plot()
        else:
            phi.value = phi.old.value
            dt /= 2.
```

This involves about the same amount of code in your script (a little less, actually) and none of the additional 100+ lines of code in [`PIDStepper`](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/fipy/generated/fipy.steppers.html#fipy.steppers.pidStepper.PIDStepper) and [`Stepper`](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/fipy/generated/fipy.steppers.html#fipy.steppers.stepper.Stepper).

None of these have been tuned, and this diffusion problem isn't much of a test as it's unconditionally stable, but once they get going, all exhibit about the same acceleration.
[image]

Comment: Very useful indeed thanks, I'll try something along the lines of your current practice. Seems simpler yet effective.